# Running Angular 4 + Core 2.0 on IIS failing to start up

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis-7

I have an application written in *ASP.Net Core 2.0* using the *Visual Studio Angular 2* template that I can run successfully on my local IIS installation and local commandline but fails on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

From my local command line I can run:

```
dotnet myApp.dll
```

And the application runs successfully until ASP.Net core 2.0.  When I copy the deployed application to my 2012 server (where the Core 2.0 runtime as been installed), I cannot call the same dotnet command (both calls are from within the root deployment folder for the app myApp).

On my desktop, the result is a web site that is listening at 5000 (ASP.Net core 2's default port I'm assuming) when running from the published site locations.

However, when I run this same command on the server, I get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (We
bpack dev middleware failed because of an error while loading 'aspnet-webpack'.
Error was: Error: Cannot find module 'aspnet-webpack'....
....
....
) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException:
Webpack dev middleware failed because of an error while loading 'aspnet-webpack'
. Error was: Error: Cannot find module 'aspnet-webpack'
```

When I look up aspnet-webpack from npmjs.com, I note that this module is "This NPM package is an internal implementation detail of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices NuGet package" according to NPM.

I'm assuming that somehow my Core 2.0 install in missing or not able to reference **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices**, but at this point I'm not sure where I should be looking for this.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly call `dotnet restore`?

Comment: Wouldn't this require the dotnet SDK? If you're on a deployed system, you should only need the runtime, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your system variables (*right click My PC > Properties > Environment Variables*). ***ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT*** has to be set to either **Staging** or **Production** if you do not have the **dotnet sdk** installed.

Once you change that value, change it in your project (*Properties > Debug tab*) as well. Redeploy your project and restart your server. You should see the site working now.

Good luck!